# How to use xpath toI find a label attribute in an arbitrary place

Tags: html, xpath, label

I need to be able to find a label attribute using xpath when the label is buried arbitrarily deep in the HTML.  I need to be able to just say something like //*[label] and have it find the first label in the HTML, but it won't.  Is there any way to do this?  Hopefully my questions was descriptive enough.  Thanks.

Comment: By label do you mean attribute? I am not personally aware of a 'label' in XML (as a programmatic element/aspect of the language)

Comment: @AaronMarcus Yes, I do mean an attribute I believe (sorry my terminology knowledge is not the best).  It is the same type of thing as a div.  I am using it to search through HTML, not XML

Comment: missed that tag! sorry.  I play around more with XPath in XML, not HTML, sorry! and apparently in your post as well, lol.

Answer (score 5):

If your label is associated with an input I would suggest using "for" attribute to search it.

```
e.g : //label[@for='input_id']
```

I would discourage the user of text label if you want only one element. Take in account also that label text can be changed often and they are language dependent.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a misunderstanding, but possibly an answer - in case it's about a `<label>`-element like e.g.

```
<label for="first">First Name</label>
```

the XPath `//label/text()` gets the value - First Name - , the XPath `//label` the whole label-element `<label for="first">First Name</label>`. In case you mean something else, please provide more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

XPath expression to match **any** label in the document :

```
//label
```

XPath expression to match **only the first** label found :

```
(//label)[1]
```